# How can i handle duplicate records in MySQL database in microservice architecture?

Tags: mysql, spring-data-jpa, microservices

Due to an duplicate events coming from an event-driven architecture, there are duplicate records being saved to the database.

This is causing an issue. I did add duplicate constraint to the table, but now I don't know how to handle the exception in case of saveAll.

One thought that comes to my mind is a recursive approach.. but since it is unpredictable as to how many duplicate events may occur, the no. of retries cannot be determined and obviously, I cannot use an infinite recursive loop.

Comment: If you can recognize they are duplicate events, is there a reason your event ingress service can't recognize that?

Comment: I am using RabitMQ which guarantees atleast once delivery. So there will be duplicates.

Comment: Just an idea: insert values into an in-memory cache after you insert them in the database successfully. But the code should check for the value in the cache before trying to insert to the database. The cache has a TTL defined so that the value will still be there as your queue handles duplicate events in the queue (for example, would 1 hour be long enough?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your events are firstly saved to database, you can just make a unique index, then duplicate records cannot be inserted.

For Mysql, "insert ignore ...." can just ignore duplicates.

For Postgres "insert ... on conflict do nothing" can just ignore duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is exactly-once delivery guarantee. This approach requires an event to be acknowledge for both producer and consumer to make sure the event is not lost.

Some message brokers have this feature; for example, kafka supports message dedup for producers.

Since you are using RabbitMQ, I would look into making event consumption an idempotent operation - basically it should be callable many times without producing any non-desired results.

In your case, I would validate events as they are consumed - which is basically called "fix data on write" - when an event is consumed, you know how the record will look like - do a check before inserting.

For completeness - you could fix your data on read - by removing duplicates; but that's less desirable approach as having a correct data set is something easier to reason about.

Another option is to use distributed transaction - a record is marked as read from a queue only if it was saved to db. This works, but requires lots of complexity. Checking for duplicates on write seems like the best bet for you.